# How Can I merge Develop Branch Into Master on Github?

Tags: git, github

I have created a feature branch and made some changes. I committed these changes, and made a pull request on `Github`, then merged the changes to develop branch.

How can I now merge develop into master branch on `Github`?

If I switch to `develop` and attempt a pull request, the green button is disabled...

[image: github screenshot]

Comment: Don’t you need to write a title and comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a title, then it will work.
Write a comment with the changes you've made.